# How to ignore formatting imports with vscode and black by shortcut?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-black, isort

[Can Black be configured to ignore imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637816/can-black-be-configured-to-ignore-import)

In this question, they added

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
```

in `setting.json` to control whether using black to format imports or not. But I like to use shortcut in vscode  (opt+shift+f) to format my code, because I need to select if implementing black in my code and I must need to save files at the same time. It seems this json doesn't work for shortcuts in vscode.

I added the

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": false
```

in my `setting.json`.
But when I use shortcut to format imports, it still doesn't work.

I want to use black for code and isort for imports with shortcuts to choose if implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `isort` as your preferred import sorter by add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```json
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports.isort": "explicit"
        }
    },
```